# how to use adwords api to grab all keywords?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

i set up an Google ad-words api and seems to work fine.

I can get `GetAllCampaigns`, `GetAllAdGroupCriteria` and `GetAllAdGroups`.

but i want to get all keywords from a specific group/campaign, and the related data like: clicks, spent money.

i found this code online but im not sure how to use it:

```
$report = getKeywordXmlReport( 
    'Report Name',          // String name 
    '2009-04-01',                           // String startDay 
    '2009-04-30',                   // String endDay 
    array('Campaign', 'AdGroup', 'Keyword', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 
    'CTR', 'CPC', 'AveragePosition'),  // [String] selectedColumns 
    array('Monthly'),       // [String] aggregationTypes 
    array('54105960'),                        // [Integer] campaigns 
    array(),                        // [String] campaignStatuses 
    array(),                        // [Integer] adGroups 
    array(),                        // [String] adGroupStatuses 
    array(),                        // [String] keywords 
    array(),                        // [String] keywordStatuses 
    'SearchOnly',           // String adWordsType 
    'Broad',                        // String keywordType 
    false,                          // Boolean isCrossClient 
    array(),                        // [String] clientEmails 
    false,                          // Boolean includeZeroImpression 
    30,                                     // Integer sleepTime 
    false,                          // Boolean validateFirst 
    false                           // Boolean onlyReturnDownloadUrl
```

);

i need to know what class to load and what function to use.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Google's PHP Adwords client library?  It's at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/ and is full of examples.

If you're looking for keyword ("adgroup criteria," in their lingo) performance numbers then you need to create a report with the fields you want, add it, then download it after its complete.  It's somewhat involved.

I suggest you check out http://www.google.com/codesearch#Fu0vUbQ37f4/trunk/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Util/TestUtils.php for their example code for running reports.

Comment: that is what i have, but there is no example on how to get the keywords